How best to charge a 120 V series assembled Li-po?
I purchased ten 12 V, 30 Ah batteries to be run in series up to 120 V. The problem is that they each come with a 12 V, 3 A internal BMS.
I assume I must disconnect their internal BMS as the combined voltage will inevitably fry them. I have considered fabricating a massive 10-contact rail to connect in series for output and then disengage to allow for individual 12 V charging.  Any ideas how best to achieve my goal?

"the combined voltage will inevitably fry them" - no, each BMS only sees the voltage across its own battery. What you need is a proper charger that will balance the cells.
